# RIA Service EF creating a MessageObject with Lists of Entities as properties

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

I have created a message object with three properties that are three list of three different entity types.  I created the message class because I am trying to do a search all that will return all the entities that fit the search criteria.  I would like to do this in one call, not three (one for each entity) separate calls.  It compiles and the client side designer is generating the entities, the service's Search All method, the message object class, but not the message object properties.
Is this possible with RIA Services? and if so what can you explain what I am doing wrong and why?  Thanks!

Server side class declaration:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class SearchAllMessage
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<Entity1> Entity1List { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Entity2> Entity2List { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Entity3> Entity3List { get; set; }
}
```

Client side designer generated code:

```
/// <summary>
/// The 'SearchAllMessage' class.
/// </summary>
[DataContract(Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SharebackMaintenance.RiaService.Web")]
public sealed partial class SearchAllMessage : ComplexObject
{

    #region Extensibility Method Definitions

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is invoked from the constructor once initialization is complete and
    /// can be used for further object setup.
    /// </summary>
    partial void OnCreated();

    #endregion


    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SearchAllMessage"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public SearchAllMessage()
    {
        this.OnCreated();
    }
}
```

Service's method signature:

```
 [Invoke]
 public SearchAllMessage SearchAll(string fiterA, string filterB, int filterC)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `SearchAllMessage` and its contained items are read-only, you should mark it up as a `ComplexType`. All you have to do is add an attribute to each of the classes involved (`SearchAllMessage`, `Entity1`, etc.)

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
[ComplexType]
public class SearchAllMessage
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<Entity1> Entity1List { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Entity2> Entity2List { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Entity3> Entity3List { get; set; }
}
```

The `ComplexTypeAttribute` is a member of the `EntityFramework` assembly.

If you are intending to make the entities queryable and updatable, then you'll need to go down the path of using `[Association(...)]`, `[Include]`, and `[Composition]`.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ed!  I added the [ComplexTypeAttribute] to the class and now in the client-side generated file I am seeing " - The attribute "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ComplexTypeAttribute' is not visible in the client project 'MyProject.RiaService'. Are you missing an assembly reference?  I couldn't find any Silverlight 4 dll with the ComplexTypeAttribute class.  Do you know what Silverlight 4 dll has that attribute?  Do I need to add this class to the MyDomainService.metadata.cs file as well?

Comment: BTW I have WCF RIA Servics V1.0 SP2

Comment: Apologies, the attribute is in the EntityFramework DLL. I had, until now, assumed it was from the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations or  WCF RIA assemblies.